# array of comma separated string IN in clause mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I have a array like that :

```
 $myarray=  'zzz,aaa,bbb'  ;
```

and want use it in mysql IN clause like that :

```
 "...  WHERE ids IN ($myarray) "   // didnt work 
 "...  WHERE ids IN ('$myarray') " // didnt work
```

the error im getting is that the first value in that array `zzz` says that zzz is not a column name . so i understand that i must separate the values with quotes to be like that :

```
 $myarray=  ' "zzz","aaa","bbb" '  ;
```

But i have no clue to do that . any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Because it really isn't an array, it's a string. You need to `implode` with the appropriate quotes and commas.

Comment: The end result should look like this: `WHERE ids IN ('zzz','aaa','bbb')`

Comment: @JayBlanchard  you mean i use this ` ids IN implode(", ", $myarray); `  ?

Comment: Lot's of good answers here @ScooterDaraf - the one liners are especially elegant. My example shows what is going on line by line.

Comment: As a side note, you should maybe not call your variable $myarray if it isnt an array. Giving good names, makes it easier to maintain code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `explode()` your string and then `implode()` it -

```
$myarray = 'zzz,aaa,bbb'; 
$realArray = explode(',', $myarray);
$stringForIn = "'" . implode("','", $realArray) . "'";
echo "WHERE ids IN ($stringForIn)";
```

Comment: I dont know why id doesnt work with 2 strings and more, it works just with single string

Comment: Without knowing more about your database it would be hard to know why it isn't working. Can you update your original post with the entire query and your table layout @ScooterDaraf?

Comment: Can you echo the full query @ScooterDaraf? So far I'm not seeing an issue.

Comment: Let us know if you need us to look further @ScooterDaraf. Make sure to update your post with the appropriate code so we can see what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

```
$myarray = 'zzz,aaa,bbb';
$myarray = implode("','",explode(',',$myarray));
$query   = "..... WHERE ids IN ('$myarray')";
```

Comment: I dont know why id doesnt work with 2 strings and more, it works just with single string .

Answer (score 1):

Try that :

```
$myarray=  'zzz,aaa,bbb'  ; 
echo implode '"' . ('","', explode(',', $myarray)) . '"';
```